# Nand gate for binary addition instead of XOR gate

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, nand

i am a novice to electronics,actually i am java and android developer who doesn't know the very basic concepts of computing and trying to learn from ground level.
i was checking out a video which explains about logical gates very well but i did not understand on thing in this pic:

[image]

the xor gate has NAND gate and OR gates with output connecting to  AND gate so if both switches are on out put of right bulb will be off. my question is if instead of XOR gate we put just NAND gate isn't it gonna be same thing? because all we want is output off if both switches are on.

Comment: XOR gate's truth table and NAND truth table aren't same. What if both inputs are zero? Its supposed to be 0 but NAND gives different.

Comment: hi thanx,thank you,but how nand gate gives output 1 while its inputs are off?

Comment: A NAND gate gives output 1 if *either* input is off, which includes the case of *both* inputs being off.

Comment: You may be missing the idea that gates have their own power supply, not always shown on diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

> my question is if instead of XOR gate we put just NAND gate isn't it gonna be same thing? because all we want is output off if both switches are on.

Nope. In binary,

```
0 + 0 =  00
0 + 1 =  01
1 + 0 =  01
1 + 1 =  10
```

As you can see, a NAND gate would give incorrect results (the first line would have 0+0=01 instead of 00).

Comment: thank you,but how nand gate gives output 1 while its inputs are off?

Comment: Well, check out the truth table of NAND gate ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate

Comment: @NavSandhu gates don't exist in isolation, they have separate supply and ground lines that aren't shown in logic diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

These are all examples of XOR Boolean logic.

Either input high, otherwise low =  EXCLUSIVE OR

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7YAR0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>